# python example for reading multiple protobuf messages from a stream

Tags: python, stream, protocol-buffers

I'm working with data from spinn3r, which consists of multiple different protobuf messages serialized into a byte stream:

http://code.google.com/p/spinn3r-client/wiki/Protostream

"A protostream is a stream of protocol buffer messages, encoded on the wire as length prefixed varints according to the Google protocol buffer specification. The stream has three parts: a header, the payload, and a tail marker."

This seems like a pretty standard use case for protobufs.  In fact, protobuf core distribution provides CodedInputStream for both C++ and Java.  But, it appears that protobuf does not provide such a tool for python -- the 'internal' tools are not setup for this kind of external use:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/protobuf/xgmUqXVsK-o

So... before I go and cobble together a python varint parser and tools for parsing a stream of different message types:  does anyone know of any tools for this?

Why is it missing from protobuf?  (Or am I just failing to find it?)

This seems like a big gap for protobuf, especially when compared to thrift's equivalent tools for both 'transport' and 'protocol'.  Am I viewing that correctly?

Comment: What about https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated ?

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the code in the other answer is potentially lifted from [here](https://code.google.com/r/avenka-co1/source/browse/src/python/varint.py?spec=svn2b97a552eb2c39cfe62b62dbc303b6e86c47ec4b&name=series34&r=2b97a552eb2c39cfe62b62dbc303b6e86c47ec4b).  Check the licence before using this file but I managed to get it to read `varint32`s using code such as this:

```
import sys
import myprotocol_pb2 as proto
import varint # (this is the varint.py file)

data = open("filename.bin", "rb").read() # read file as string
decoder = varint.decodeVarint32          # get a varint32 decoder
                                         # others are available in varint.py

next_pos, pos = 0, 0
while pos < len(data):
    msg = proto.Msg()                    # your message type
    next_pos, pos = decoder(data, pos)
    msg.ParseFromString(data[pos:pos + next_pos])

    # use parsed message

    pos += next_pos
print "done!"
```

This is very simple code designed to load messages of a single type delimited by `varint32`s which describe the next message's size.

---

**Update**: It may also be possible to include this file directly from the protobuf library by using:

```
from google.protobuf.internal.decoder import _DecodeVarint32
```

Comment: For newer stuff, I get the decoder via `from google.protobuf.internal.decoder import _DecodeVarint32`

Comment: I've had to do this a number of times recently. I wasn't able to figure out the `msg.type == proto.Msg.END` condition, but simply doing `while pos < len(data):` works great for me.

Comment: Of course, makes sense, answer updated. Thanks @Moodragonx

Comment: just curious, this looks to be creating a new object of type `Msg` in each loop, what was Google's rationale for this? Is this overhead expensive?

Comment: @Tommy To clarify this isn't google code, this is my code as an example of how one might solve this problem in Python.  I am not a Python expert but even if you clear the Message object to reuse it, its binary data will still have to be copied from the stream anyway.  If you want a no-copy solution perhaps Python isn't the way to go; I primarily use protobufs in C++.

Answer (score 8):

I've implemented a [small python package](https://github.com/cartoonist/pystream-protobuf) to serialize multiple protobuf messages into a stream and deserialize them from a stream. You can install it by `pip`:

```
pip install pystream-protobuf
```

Here's a sample code writing two lists of protobuf messages in to a file:

```py
import stream

with stream.open("test.gam", "wb") as ostream:
    ostream.write(*objects_list)
    ostream.write(*another_objects_list)
```

and then reading the same messages (e.g. Alignment messages defined in `vg_pb2.py`) from the stream:

```py
import stream
import vg_pb2

alns_list = []
with stream.open("test.gam", "rb") as istream:
    for data in istream:
        aln = vg_pb2.Alignment()
        aln.ParseFromString(data)
        alns_list.append(aln)
```

Comment: This package offers builtin gzip compression.

Answer (score -3):

This is simple enough that I can see why maybe nobody has bothered to make a reusable tool:

```
'''
Parses multiple protobuf messages from a stream of spinn3r data
'''

import sys
sys.path.append('python_proto/src')
import spinn3rApi_pb2
import protoStream_pb2

data = open('8mny44bs6tYqfnofg0ELPg.protostream').read()

def _VarintDecoder(mask):
    '''Like _VarintDecoder() but decodes signed values.'''

    local_ord = ord
    def DecodeVarint(buffer, pos):
        result = 0
        shift = 0
        while 1:
            b = local_ord(buffer[pos])
            result |= ((b & 0x7f) << shift)
            pos += 1
            if not (b & 0x80):
                if result > 0x7fffffffffffffff:
                    result -= (1 << 64)
                    result |= ~mask
                else:
                    result &= mask
                return (result, pos)
            shift += 7
            if shift >= 64:
                ## need to create (and also catch) this exception class...
                raise _DecodeError('Too many bytes when decoding varint.')
    return DecodeVarint

## get a 64bit varint decoder
decoder = _VarintDecoder((1<<64) - 1)

## get the three types of protobuf messages we expect to see
header    = protoStream_pb2.ProtoStreamHeader()
delimiter = protoStream_pb2.ProtoStreamDelimiter()
entry     = spinn3rApi_pb2.Entry()

## get the header
pos = 0
next_pos, pos = decoder(data, pos)
header.ParseFromString(data[pos:pos + next_pos])
## should check its contents

while 1:
    pos += next_pos
    next_pos, pos = decoder(data, pos)
    delimiter.ParseFromString(data[pos:pos + next_pos])

    if delimiter.delimiter_type == delimiter.END:
        break

    pos += next_pos
    next_pos, pos = decoder(data, pos)
    entry.ParseFromString(data[pos:pos + next_pos])
    print entry
```

Comment: The line in `DecodeVarint` where the return is done: `return (result, pos)` is indented one too far. Edited to correct.